# Manipulator missing for some reason

Tags: 3d-manipulator

I was just creating a little roblox GFX for someone. I was halfway done, and I logged off for the day, but then the manipulator was gone, I am not sure why. Here is a picture.

***Picture***
https://gyazo.com/dcc4148edc2fe26bf2639fb6ecac4e2b

Note: I grouped things using shift G, if that has anything to do about it, thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Turn on *"show gizmo"* button:

[image]

Comment: Oh, lol, thanks for you help.